# Unable to develop site locally :-(

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, dreamweaver, wampserver

I want to develop a site to work on an **Apache server with a MySQL DB; using phpmyadmin**.

I have IIS7 installed on my machine - I attempted to remove it through Windows 7 variety of add/remove programs (which was apparently successful); but it turns out: no dice.

I've installed WAMP. Due to IIS hogging port 80 I've changed the listen configuration to that of port 8080. This works.

However, phpmyadmin on WAMP failed to run due to a previous installation of MySQL; so I removed its installation.

phpmyadmin subsequently threw a different error

> 2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Which I pretty much expected as MySQL was probably entirely uninstalled on the machine.

I did a fresh install of WAMP hoping that this would fix the problem. Unfortunately this does not seem to be the case. This surprised me as I thought that it was bundled in with WAMP.

The MySQL log:

```
 121021 18:30:54 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121021 18:30:54 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121021 18:30:54 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
121021 18:30:54 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121021 18:30:54 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
121021 18:30:54 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121021 18:30:54 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
121021 18:30:54  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
121021 18:30:55 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
121021 18:30:55 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '(null)'; port: 3306
121021 18:30:55 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '::';
121021 18:30:55 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
121021 18:30:55 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
121021 18:30:56 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
121021 18:30:56 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.24-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

With the absence of a local developing environment I would at a stretch be prepared to use a remote server. However, programs such as Dreamweaver seem to refuse this option out of hand on the basis that they are not established as 'testing servers'. When the remote server is selected as a testing server, connections throw a 404 error.

This leaves me with a final resort of manually writing all my code, including database manipulation, and relaying to remote server via ftp. I'd appreciate any suggestions which improves upon this set-up.

P.S. The remote server blocks connects through port 3306

Comment: Standard windows firewall, yes.

Comment: Is it permitting localhost traffic on port 3306?

Comment: I don't know if you mean my machine or remote server; but I have no reason to believe that there is anything the matter with the MySQL of the remote server, or that it wouldn't process any writes or reads of any of its hosted databases by sites that are uploaded to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL was initially not working with Wamp due to extant information which Wamp wasn't expecting (it automatically attempts to log into phpmyadmin with some default combination such as username = root and password = no).

Doing a full reinstall of MySQL, and ignoring Wamp, seemed to fix the problem.